# How can I get an XElement's .InnerText value in Linq to XML?

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-xml, kml

I'm trying to extract the polygons from placemarks in a KML file. So far so good:

```
Imports <xmlns:g='http://earth.google.com/kml/2.0'>
Imports System.Xml.Linq

Partial Class Test_ImportPolygons
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim Kml As XDocument = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("../kmlimport/ga.kml"))
        For Each Placemark As XElement In Kml.<g:Document>.<g:Folder>.<g:Placemark>
            Dim Name As String = Placemark.<g:name>.Value
            ...
        Next
    End Sub

End Class
```

I'd like to capture the entire `<polygon>...</polygon>` block as a string. I tried something like this (where the ... is above):

```
        Dim Polygon as String = Placemark.<g:Polygon>.InnerText
```

but the XElement object doesn't have an InnerText property, or any equivalent as far as I can tell. How do I grab the raw XML that defines an XElement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I was missing was that `Placemark.<g:Polygon>` is a collection of XElements, not a single XElement. This works:

```
    For Each Placemark As XElement In Kml.<g:Document>.<g:Folder>.<g:Placemark>
        Dim Name As String = Placemark.<g:name>.Value
        Dim PolygonsXml As String = ""
        For Each Polygon As XElement In Placemark.<g:Polygon>
            PolygonsXml &= Polygon.ToString
        Next
    Next
```

XElement.ToString is the equivalent of InnerText, as tbrownell suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
Placemark.ToString()
```

Comment: Yes, but that gives me the whole Placemark node, whereas I just want the Polygon. What I was missing was that `Placemark.<g:Polygon>` is a collection of XElements, not a single XElement.

Answer (score 0):

I missed the Enumeration also. When using .Value it is possible to receive a null exception. Try the equivelent of this instead:

```
(string)Placemark.<g:name>
```

Sorry not sure of the VB syntax,,,it has been a while since I have coded in VB.